# XCode 4 problem, always showing target view when stops at a break point

Tags: iphone, xcode, ide

I just upgraded to XCode 4.0.2 and ran into a strange issue. Every time when the app stops at a breakpoint, XCode shows the target view instead of the .m file. When I manually click the file and show it, and click step, then the IDE switches to the target view again. This makes debugging virtually impossible. THis only happens to my own project. Sample projects work fine. Please help, it drives me nuts and I can not find where did I get the settings wrong.

P.S, this project worked fine on XCode 3, after upgrading to Xcode 4 I had problems with my targets. After wrestling a while with the schemes it finally builds and runs fine, but I can not do debugging when making changes because of this. I am not sure if I messed up some settings during the time to change the scheme and target settings.
Thanks
Ray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem, but still not having the real solution. The situation is that the project was originally in one directory called WorldClock, after having problems when installed XCode 4, I copied the folder to another folder called WorldClockNew, and started in this folder. However somehow the build directory is still pointing to the old directory. After deleting the Build folder under WorldClock, this problem went away. However I still can not find where in the XCode settings to correct the Build path..